# error: Cannot find getter for field; When data classes used with Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have this data class:

```
@Entity(tableName = User.TABLE_NAME)
data class User(
        @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = User.id) var id: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = User.name) var name: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = User.password) var password: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = User.modDate) var modDate: DateTime = DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0)
)
```

And I get the following error while compiling:

```
e: C:\Users\Tibi\AndroidStudioProjects\Android_Sales\EventApp\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\tiborfarago\eventapp\database\User.java:11: error: Cannot find getter for field.
    private java.lang.String id$1;
                             ^
e: C:\Users\Tibi\AndroidStudioProjects\Android_Sales\EventApp\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\tiborfarago\eventapp\database\User.java:14: error: Cannot find getter for field.
    private java.lang.String name$1;
                             ^
e: C:\Users\Tibi\AndroidStudioProjects\Android_Sales\EventApp\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\tiborfarago\eventapp\database\User.java:17: error: Cannot find getter for field.
    private java.lang.String password$1;
                             ^
e: C:\Users\Tibi\AndroidStudioProjects\Android_Sales\EventApp\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\tiborfarago\eventapp\database\User.java:20: error: Cannot find getter for field.
    private org.joda.time.DateTime modDate$1;
                                   ^
```

If I recreate the class in Java, the application runs fine.

I am not really sure what additional information I should provide because I use everything as I have before.

What strange to me is that it doesn't miss the setters, only the getters.
Edit: Now the setters are missing too.

Edit2:
For some reason, this works:

```
@Entity(tableName = "sfdfs")
data class Eventdasdsa(
        @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "s") var idgfgh: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = "sfdsfdfs") var locatgfhgfionId: String? = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = "hhhhjghjg") var nafhfhgffme: String? = ""
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out:

In the data class's body I have a companion object that contains const vals. These variables' names were the same as the data class's field names and this caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

These come from `abstract class CloudDBZoneObject` & `extends CloudDBZoneObject`. One would have to replicate these fields into each class, in order to add a Room `@Ignore` annotation.

```
@Ignore private String entityName;
@Ignore private String packageName;
@Ignore private long mObjectSize;
```

This would at least make it build.

---

But there's still further compatibility issues with Room, eg. the default constructor:

> There is no default constructor available in `com.huawei.agconnect.cloud.database.CloudDBZoneObject`.

And also data-binding is an issue, since it's not an `Observable`:

> Bindable must be on a member in an Observable class. XY is not Observable.

---

Not directly using/binding `CloudDBZoneObject` might make sense.